# Wagtail - how to (correctly) get other pages/models

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Using Wagtail which is the more appropriate way of getting the records of other pages/models.

```py
# models.py

def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context['children'] = ArticleDetailPage.objects.live().public()[:3]
    return context
```

```html
# template.html

{% for item in children %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Or,

```py
# models.py

def articles(self):
    articles = ArticleDetailPage.objects.live().public()[:3]
    return articles
```

```html
# template.html

{% for item in page.articles %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Both of these methods work and I see the former often used in the docs and either one used elsewhere. Is there a difference at all to which one is used in terms of performance or "correctness" or is it simply personal preference?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIW, it's just personal preference. The first one is more explicit, the second one keeps your context more clean. The only difference I can think of is that in the second option `ArticleDetailPage.objects.live().public()[:3]` is only called when you actually include `{{page.articles}}` in your template, which could lead to a tiny boost in performance if the query is quite complex.

In general I tend to wrap these kind of variables in a property when either:

1. I know there is an explicit relationship there. So in this case, when they're subpages of the page rendering the template. A variable like `shopping_cart` or `breadcrumb` would be less likely to be coupled to the page itself.

or

2. The variable is used in other parts of my Django/Wagtail code apart from the template. It's very much possible that I want to access the articles of a page from somewhere else.

Otherwise, I just pass it directly in the context.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just getting started with Django/Wagtail so getting the hang of it. I read some documentation (*reference below) trying to see how it runs under the hood to know which way is preferable but don't understand it fully yet so thought I'd ask. Could you elaborate on your second point? Or any docs for the example? (*reference - (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/template/base/), (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context))